# Added 1 store view - now new orders have the wrong ordernumber

Tags: orders, onepage-checkout, multistore, store-view

after adding 1 storeview to the default, Magento chooses the new ordernumber for this storeview for each and every new order instead of using the default numbers.

Does anybody know where I can trigger this?
I thought, the default store view would be used by Magento as default for the ordernumbers, but it seems, he likes the new storeview more. That's puzzling.

Any hint or shed of light here would be greatly apprechiated!

Cheers,
Johannes

Comment: Johannes,can you explain in more details...

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/) is what you might be looking for.
Query:

> UPDATE eav_entity_store
>   INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
>   SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXXX'
>   WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';

Another option is [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/25668/#t154594), but i didnt test it.

Comment: hi mbalparda - woah! That was quick! Thanks a dozen for the link!

However - after the first order after establishing the new store-view, I saw that this new order began with Magento's standart number, i.e. "2000001" and I already changed that. Our default store-view has like "abc123456" and now our 2. store-view I set up with like "def7891011" - so that's ok.

BUT, the point is, any new order now uses the second order-numbers: so "def7891011", "def7891012" and counting up.

Comment: That was the whole tutorial purpose, to unify all stores order_id.

Comment: Ah! Ok! So thank you even more! 
Well, later we would like to seperate them, so then it just makes sense if Magento creates a new number-circle (sp?) for each store-view and we would like to keep that.
That beeing the case, how can I tell Magento to switch back to the default order-numbers?

Comment: You will have to debug the query and set the increment id per store the same way you set both or in the admin the same way you made it before.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you kindly again, mbalparda! Alas, I'm not firm with SQL Queries, so I either have to learn a bit or try and find somebody who can formulate this safely - it's a running store, you know, and I don't want to mix things up here... ;-)

Comment: You might want to mark this question as resolved and start a new question with the correct title. It might be easier to resolve.